# How to display encoded base 64 embedded images in JEditorPaneContent

Tags: java

I have HTML file with encoded base64 image and image is not displaying. Need some help. Thanks for the help.

```
private void setFirstPage(String p_pageURL) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(aHelpFilesLocation + p_pageURL.trim());

    // Select a page from the current title
    // Display that page in the content window

    url = new URL("file:C://form_3.html");

    jEditorPaneContent.setPage(url);       
    jScrollPaneContent.requestFocus();
```

Below is the html file.

```html
<h1>
  <strong>Deviation Form:</strong> 3<br />
  <strong>Created for SKU:</strong> 123456<br />
  <strong>Only for Machine</strong> 34<br />
  <strong>Responsible Person(s):</strong><br />
  <strong>Active:</strong> 1<br />
  <strong>Status:</strong><br />
  <strong>Reason:</strong> reason<br />
</h1>
<p>
  <br />
</p>
<p>
  <img src=
  "data:image/png;base64,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" />
  <img src=
  "data:image/png;base64,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" />
  </p>
```

Comment: If you are talking about the arrows, well, they are showing for me.

Comment: The images (arrows) are not displaying inside JEditorPane. Is there a way to display an image in a JEditorPane?